# MongoDB aggregation of large amounts of data

Tags: mongodb, performance, aggregation-framework

I am doing aggregation on a really large amounts of data and I want to group this data by a date field. So I am doing a projection first so I can add this field:

```
$project: {
//include other fields
GroupDate: {
   year: { $year: "$Date" },
   month: { $month: "$Date" },
   week: { $week: "$Date" }
} }
```

and then i group by this "GroupDate".

I was wondering what is the impact of this projection to the execution speed of the aggregation?

Comment: Test it with your own data. It's really hard to provide specifics without having your data in your computing environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This projection is not a big deal, it has minor impact on whole execution complexity. You can make simple tests **with** and **without** this step to find concrete numbers for your case, but, as I said, it just one additional step for Aggregation framework.

If you grouping by date, [this post](http://www.kamsky.org/1/post/2013/03/stupid-date-tricks-with-aggregation-framework.html) might be helpful